# iPhone app is automatically being logged off/killed after approximately every 20 minutes

Tags: iphone, background, task

PLATFORM AND VERSION iOS
iPhone 4s, iOS version 5.1.1

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM
 Whenever my application is placed in the background it is automatically being logged off / killed after approximately every 20 minutes. In our application we have the ability to upload data if the app is moved to background. If I comment out this section, the application is no longer killed.

The application gets logged off (killed by the operating system) even if there is no activity or no user intervention and its just sitting in the background.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE
 Please find below the code snippet which is uploading the attachments 
 in the background.

```
 -(void) endTaskWidthIdentifier:(NSNumber *)paramIdentifier{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier identifier = [paramIdentifier integerValue];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:identifier]; }

 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
        backgroundTaskIdentifier = [application 
 beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSNumber *backgroundTask = [NSNumber 
 numberWithInteger:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
        [self 
 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(endTaskWidthIdentifier:)
 withObject:backgroundTask waitUntilDone:YES];
        backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
 }
```

Once this code is executed, the application logs out after 15-20 minutes when kept in the background with no user intervention.

If I comment this code, application remains in the background and does not exits and remains in the suspended mode.

Question:

What is wrong with this code. What is this code doing that it should not?